# Why does my text clustering do this

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, tf-idf

I have an unlabeled dataset with product names. For example, baseball shirt, bomber jacket, active classic boxer, etc.

I created a tf-idf matrix with the data then I ran k-means on the matrix. I plotted a within-cluster sum of squares to find the best k which is 5.

After clustering I figured out the cosine similarity between documents

```
# cosine similarity between each document
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
dist = 1.0 - cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix)
print dist
```

Then I used MDS on dist to reduce it to 2 dimensions so I can plot the clusters

```
from sklearn.manifold import MDS
mds = MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity="precomputed", random_state=1)
xs, ys = pos[:, 0], pos[:, 1]
```

The cluster plot looks pretty good except for the circumference. Is there a reason why it is doing this? The rest of the clusters seem like they are clustering around a similar area.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

TF-IDF only works for **long text**.

Because of this, almost every document is completely different from every other, and they "fan out" like this.

I doubt that k-means worked either.

Comment: So does that mean the ones that are not around the circumference are not completely different and are long text?

Comment: Study them, you have the data. I'd assume **most texts here are just completely different from *any* other text**, so the visualization tries to space them evenly ("uniform"). For TF-IDF to wok well, your texts should have 100+ words *each*!